# How to use standard input redirection to a file while debugging using cppdbg in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gdb, stdin, vscode-debugger

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run GDB",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/mnt/e/Fortran_Codes/wrfchembc_CT/wrfchembc_CT_pkg/wrfchembcCT",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/mnt/e/Fortran_Codes/wrfchembc_CT/wrfchembc_CT_pkg/",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "make",
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is the launch.json file used for debugging a Fortran code. I am able to start debugging but without an input file with a Fortran namelist. What should I add here such that the debugger accepts the input file too.
Actually the executable takes in the input file as follows:

```
wrfchembcCT < wrfchembc_namelist
```

But I am not able to debug while passing the data file to the Fortran code.

Answer (score 1):

all arguments with redirection symbols `<>|` are quoted, so redirection will not work in VSC

Option is to add a CLI argument to the application that will open the file in the argument as `stdin`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run GDB",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/mnt/e/Fortran_Codes/wrfchembc_CT/wrfchembc_CT_pkg/wrfchembcCT",
            "args": ["--stdin", "wrfchembc_namelist"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/mnt/e/Fortran_Codes/wrfchembc_CT/wrfchembc_CT_pkg/",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "make",
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you can start the program with a task, maybe starting a shell script that has redirection. And attach the debugger to this running program.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved by providing complete path to the executable in program section. Its now working for some reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).